# Query a reference field to get the object Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I need to access a full object by one of its refs:

- I have a User collection
- I have a UserType collection
- A User can have only one UserType
- A UserType has many Users
- I need to get all the Users from one UserType using Mongodb (by the UserType ID in User for example)

How can I do this ?

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch all `USERS` with particular `UserTypeId` use below `query`

```
db.user.find({"userType.id" : "<ID HERE>"});
```

Hope this could help you.